# Find the lowest of 4 variables using only else-if statements, C++

Tags: c++

I just started c++ not too long ago. I want to find the lowest of 4 variables using only if-else statements. So far this is what i could think of. Is there anyway to shorten this?

```
float lowest;

if (assignment1<assignment2 && assignment1<assignment3 && assignment1<assignment4)
     assignment1 == lowest;           


else if (assignment2<assignment1 && assignment2<assignment3 && assignment2<assignment4)
         assignment2 == lowest;



else if (assignment3<assignment1 && assignment3<assignment2 && assignment3<assignment4)
         assignment3 == lowest;



else 
        assignment4 == lowest;
```

Comment: This code isn't even doing anything. I'm also not sure I understand the restrictions on this one - any reason why you are not allowed to use other language constructs apart from `if` and `else`?

Comment: define shorten.  less checks or less code?

Comment: @UnholySheep somehow I'd guess that's the requirements of the homework, but who knows.

Comment: lowest = assignmentX;

Comment: you can assume that if not `assignment1 < assignment2` then `assignment2 < assignment1` (same for 2-3), which would cut out three checks. Valid result, since equal elements will still be minimal

Comment: can you use macros that only use if/else checks?

Comment: How about the lowest 5 variables?  6 variables?  10 variables?  100 variables?  At some point you'll see that it becomes pointless using if-else statements for things like this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is probably an assignment designed to show them how painful life would be without loop as the next lesson will show then loops and asked to re implement it with loops.  That is how it is typically done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you allowed to do multiple assignments to `lowest`? If so:

```
float lowest = assignment1;

if (assignment2 < lowest)
    lowest = assignment2;

if (assignment3 < lowest)
    lowest = assignment3;

if (assignment4 < lowest)
    lowest = assignment4;
```

By keeping the smallest value inside `lowest`, we can simply check each value against `lowest`, and update `lowest` when a smaller value is found.